# split a number using OpenSSL's BIGNUM as quickly as possible

Tags: c, openssl, bignum

I am using OpenSSL's BIGNUM library for arbitrary precision numbers.

I need to split a number in two pieces.  I need the first n bits [0, n-1] in one number (by that I mean the n least significant bits), and the rest of the bits [n, end] in the other number.

The code I have that does works is this

```
void number_split(BIGNUM * first_n_bits, BIGNUM * the_rest, BIGNUM * number, long n) {
    int i = 0;

    BN_copy(first_n_bits, number);

    int bits = BN_num_bits(first_n_bits);

    while(bits > n) {
        BN_clear_bit(first_n_bits, --bits);
    }

    if(BN_num_bits(number) > n) {
        BN_rshift(the_rest, number, n);
    } else {
        BN_copy(the_rest, zero);
    }
}
```

I have determined that this function is one of the biggest contributors to execution time of my application, so making it a little faster would help me a lot.

The part that seems like it could be improved is the `while` loop where I am clearing the most significant bits one at a time.  I would have thought that BIGNIM would have a function for accomplishing that more efficiently, but I couldn't find it.

So, what can I do to make this faster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `BN_mask_bits()` function, which should be faster than looping over every bit.

```
// BN_num_bits(num) must be >= n
void number_split(BIGNUM *low_bits, BIGNUM *high_bits, BIGNUM *num, long n) {
  BN_copy(low_bits, num);
  BN_mask_bits(low_bits, n);
  BN_rshift(high_bits, num, n);
}
```

If it is possible that `BN_num_bits(num) < n` then add a check:

```
void number_split(BIGNUM *low_bits, BIGNUM *high_bits, BIGNUM *num, long n) {
  BN_copy(low_bits, num);
  if(BN_num_bits(num) <= n) {
    BN_copy(high_bits, zero);
  } else {
    BN_mask_bits(low_bits, n);
    BN_rshift(high_bits, num, n);
  }
}
```

Comment: One small change to your solution, `BN_mask_bits` does an in place modification of num, it doesn't put the result in a new struct like `BN_rshift` does.  So, you have to copy `num` into `low_bits` first, then mask `low_bits`

Comment: Thanks!  That works great! I got a 33% net speed up on my application from this.

Comment: @Luke, oh yes - I've updated my answer to use `BN_copy()` before `BN_mask_bits()`. Glad to hear it helped!